# My ajax/jquery script to send $_GET to php isn't working? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, get

This is the code that I'm using to send a variable (via GET) to another php file:
(basically, I click on a button, and then js gets the id and sends the id via ajax to the php file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".doClick").click(function() {
     var category=$(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax({
       url:'aFile.php',
       type:'GET',
       data: $category,
       success: function(data){
           alert("It worked?"); // this is the response
    }
 });
alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
 });
```

This is the code in my aFile.php:
The php file gets the info via $_GET[] and then assigns it to a variable and uses that variable in a function call.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
   function JS() {
 //code
});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JS()">
<?php
$category = $_GET['category'];

if (function_exists('inventory_insert')) {
echo inventory_insert('{category_name = '.$category.'}');

} else echo('warning');
?>
```

It's supposed to give me a response back on my main page, but nothing seems to be happening. I don't even get the alert I posted after the ajax script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your variable is `category` but you're sending `data: $category`

Comment: Heh, i make that mistake all the time, get used to doing variables in php and sometimes place a $ in front of the vars in my js.  Simple little mistake :)

Comment: Haha can't believe I missed that. One bug out.

Answer (score 1):

You must send key/value pair to server

to receive `$_GET['category']` your data sent in ajax needs to be either:

```
  data: 'category='+category
```

Or

```
  data: {category: category}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I fixed that and put down the correct variable, but it's still not sending back a response :/

Comment: Use a browser console to inspect the AJAX request. Will see status, response etc

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned id into category in jquery. so correct in data params.

```
 data: {category : category},
```

Send it in this way to server or php file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".doClick").click(function() {
 var category=$(this).attr('id');
 $.ajax({
   url:'aFile.php',
   type:'GET',
   data: {category : category},
   success: function(data){
       alert("It worked?"); // this is the response
}
});
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
});
```